# Week of the month/year with Windows Phone

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to get the number of the week of the year (and for the month too) with Windows Phone (Silverlight 8.1)? I use this code when I create something with C# but I can't find the class `GregorianCalendar` for Windows Phone.

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    static GregorianCalendar _gc = new GregorianCalendar();

    public static int GetWeekOfMonth(this DateTime time)
    {
        DateTime first = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1);
        return time.GetWeekOfYear() - first.GetWeekOfYear() + 1;
    }

    static int GetWeekOfYear(this DateTime time)
    {
        return _gc.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391073/how-to-get-the-number-of-weeks-in-a-given-year

Comment: Does it work with WP8.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class [**GregorianCalendar**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) is found in the `System.Globalization` namespace. From the information on MSDN (check the link), this class is also available for Windows Phone 8.1.

> **.NET for Windows Phone apps**
>
> Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8

Otherwise, check the [**Calendar.GetWeekOfYear()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx) method. This method is also found in the `System.Globalization` namespace. Method definition:

> Returns the week of the year that includes the date in the specified DateTime value.

Comment: Strange. I can't use the GregorianCalendar even if i add that using statement. It still says that i'm missing an using statement.

Comment: Awesome hint  Calendar.GetWeekOfYear() +1